# How do I disable or hide jQuery UI spinner buttons without disabling widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner, readonly, disabled-control

I originally was using the option to disable the spinner widget, but I don't want to use that, because it causes the value of the widget to be lost when the form is submitted.  What I am looking for is to set the widget to readOnly.

When I set it to read only, it correctly makes it so the user cannot type in the field, but unfortunately they can still click the up and down buttons.  I am wanting to know if there is a way to either disable or hide the spinner buttons without affecting the text part of the widget, so I can later re-enable or show those buttons.

Thanks in advance!
-David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hide the spinner controls, run this:

`$('.ui-spinner a.ui-spinner-button').css('display','none');`

To make them reappear run this:

`$('.ui-spinner a.ui-spinner-button').css('display','block');`

Change the selector value to fit your document structure.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I would have preferred to have the buttons grayed out and disabled, but hidden works well too.  This is the solution I am using.  Since I am in a function where I have a handle to the input, I used:

`jQuery(this).siblings('.ui-spinner-button').css('display', 'none');`

Comment: you should be able to do this `jQuery('.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` to disable to buttons instead of hide them.

Comment: Neat, but users can still get around this using their keyboard: up/down and page up/page down buttons

Comment: How can i hide only for a specific element?
I tried $('#element  a.ui-spinner-button').css('display','none'); and it does not work also nit's not working $('.ui-spinner element.ui-spinner-button').css('display','none');

Answer (score 0):

The other solution using jQuery:

```
$('#spinner').parent().hide()
```

or

```
$('#spinner').parent().show()
```

or pure js:

```
var sp = document.getElementById('spinner')
sp.style.display = 'none';
sp.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but a question I had and the most complete answer is [kbwood.au's response](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-disable-or-hide-jquery-ui-spinner-buttons-without-disabling-widget). Basically cancel the event in the start (or spin) event if the element is readonly. Then you don't have to worry about the up/down/page up/page down keys which are still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$("#my_input").spinner({ disabled: false });
```

http://www.medicalsuture.com.br/js/development-bundle/docs/spinner.html